# Laravel return models created_at

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have:

**Model**

```
public function getUrlAttribute() {
    dd($this->created_at);
}
```

**View**

```
@foreach($item as $item)
    {{$item->url}}
    ...
@endforeach
```

But it returns null, when in fact every row in my table has a created_at datetime. What is going wrong here?

Comment: This space between $item ->url is in your code or it's a formatting error here at StackOverflow?

Comment: Formatting, fixed.

Comment: If you need the created_at attribute, you can call it directly instead of using a function

Comment: You using sqlite by a chance? Have to format that carbon instance?

Comment: Post your migration / model definition

Answer (score 0):

You have to return the value.

```
public function getUrlAttribute() {
    return $this->created_at;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that for whatever reason the `created_at` column was not selected when creating the model. What do you get if you do the following?

```php
dd($item->toArray());
```

You can also access it more directly skipping

```
$this->getCreatedAtAttribute()
```

by doing:

```
public function getUrlAttribute() {
    dd($this->attributes['created_at']);
}
```